# Is hooking in iOS/Mac possible?

Tags: ios, macos, hook

Is it possible to develop apps in iOS/Mac-OSx which needs hooking in iOS/Mac (similar to what we have in windows)? and how complex is it?

Comment: It’d help if you explained what exactly hooking is.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/kb/system/hooksys.aspx

Comment: Take a look at the SIMBL plugin for injection and DTrace for introspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to hook a third-party app in MacOSX, it is possible thru InputManager.
  See the SIMBL plugin that helps doing this by managing the InputManagers for you, or ApplicationEnhencer.
  [More info here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?InputManager)
- If you want to intercept a call inside your own app, e.g. when a call to a method (possibly a system method), you can do class posing (obsolete) or method swizzling using objc_exchangeImplementations. This also works on iOS apps. [More info here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MethodSwizzling).
  Be careful anyway with this, this can potentially be dangerous, you have to know what you are doing (avoid infinite call loops, etc)
- On MacOSX, you can also do C interception like on any UNIX system, to intercept system calls. But it is a bit more tricky and low-level (and system-wide)